# Unable to Connect to SMTP Host

Tags: postfix, smtp, hosting

I am trying to configure Postfix on CentOS 6 server, and the problem is that I cannot receive mails.
I tested it on http://mxtoolbox.com/ and I get an error `Unable to Connect to SMTP Host`.

I check with `netstat -tulpn | grep :25` and I see that postfix seems to be listening to port 25 just fine.

I disabled Selinux (and rebooted) - it doesn't solve the problem.

My server is on [OVH](https://www.kimsufi.com/fr/) (if it matters. may be OVH have some firewall) And I reinstalled CentOS just now.
It's possible to see my /etc/postfix/main.cf file [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gKY0-tVKBGo9kA5fiwdvOmnv699VB-C14wKmCatqGDE/edit?usp=sharing), if you whant.
What should I do next to resolve this problem? And how can I debug SMTP connection problems?

Any help will be appreciated!

iptables output:

```
[root@jewishonline log]# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1590 packets, 285K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2264 packets, 627K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

port 25:

```
[root@jewishonline log]# netstat -ntlp | grep 25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2756/master
```

Comment: Please provide the output of 'iptables -L -v' and 'netstat -ntlp | grep 25'

Comment: @GabrielTalavera OK. I updated the question with this data.

Comment: Why is it listening on localhost only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Postfix only listens in the localhost interface.

You must edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and change the line `inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost` to `inet_interfaces = all` and restart Postfix

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: Could it be anything else? I mean, what if the `inet_interfaces` is already set to `all`?